# Can i set maxConnections in server.xml of Tomcat same as number of connections Opening system is supporting?

Tags: java, tomcat, connection

For number of  connection in tomcat two attributes are used maxConnections and acceptCount where maxConnections is maximum number of concurrent connections tomcat will support if still requests are coming OS will  accept connection till acceptCount. **Now my doubt is if on a host just one tomcat is running can i set maxConnections same as number of connection OS is supporting?**

Comment: Do you think your tomcat and applications could handle that many connections?

Comment: What i can think of, Number of thread will be bottleneck. because for each connection a different thread will be required and we can not have that many thread,please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: So your tomcat an applications **can't** handle that many connections. Do you want to allow so many users that your application will grind to a halt, or do you want to allow only a certain amount of connections that still allow the application to perform work?